# Perform Arithmetic Operations on multiple columns in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an input `spark-dataframe` named `df` as

```
+---------------+---+---+---+-----------+
|Main_CustomerID| P1| P2| P3|Total_Count|
+---------------+---+---+---+-----------+
|         725153|  1|  0|  2|          3|
|         873008|  0|  0|  3|          3|
|         625109|  1|  1|  0|          2|
+---------------+---+---+---+-----------+
```

Here,`Total_Count` is the sum of `P1,P2,P3` and `P1,P2,P3` were the `product names`. I need to find the `frequency` of each product by dividing the values of products with its `Total_Count`. I need to create a new `spark-dataframe` named `frequencyTable` as follows,

```
+---------------+------------------+---+------------------+-----------+
|Main_CustomerID|                P1| P2|                P3|Total_Count|
+---------------+------------------+---+------------------+-----------+
|         725153|0.3333333333333333|0.0|0.6666666666666666|          3|
|         873008|               0.0|0.0|               1.0|          3|
|         625109|               0.5|0.5|               0.0|          2|
+---------------+------------------+---+------------------+-----------+
```

I have done this using Scala as,

```
val df_columns = df.columns.toSeq
var frequencyTable = df
for (index <- df_columns) {
  if (index != "Main_CustomerID" && index != "Total_Count") {
  frequencyTable = frequencyTable.withColumn(index, df.col(index) / df.col("Total_Count"))
}
}
```

But I don't prefer this for loop because my `df` is of larger size. What is the optimized solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have dataframe as

```
val df = Seq(
  ("725153", 1, 0, 2, 3),
  ("873008", 0, 0, 3, 3),
  ("625109", 1, 1, 0, 2)
).toDF("Main_CustomerID", "P1", "P2", "P3", "Total_Count")

+---------------+---+---+---+-----------+
|Main_CustomerID|P1 |P2 |P3 |Total_Count|
+---------------+---+---+---+-----------+
|725153         |1  |0  |2  |3          |
|873008         |0  |0  |3  |3          |
|625109         |1  |1  |0  |2          |
+---------------+---+---+---+-----------+
```

You can simply use `foldLeft` on the columns except `Main_CustomerID`, `Total_Count` i.e. on `P1` `P2` and `P3`

```
val df_columns = df.columns.toSet - "Main_CustomerID" - "Total_Count" toList

df_columns.foldLeft(df){(tempdf, colName) => tempdf.withColumn(colName, df.col(colName) / df.col("Total_Count"))}.show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---------------+------------------+---+------------------+-----------+
|Main_CustomerID|P1                |P2 |P3                |Total_Count|
+---------------+------------------+---+------------------+-----------+
|725153         |0.3333333333333333|0.0|0.6666666666666666|3          |
|873008         |0.0               |0.0|1.0               |3          |
|625109         |0.5               |0.5|0.0               |2          |
+---------------+------------------+---+------------------+-----------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Yes.. This works perfect. But if I used foldLeft, whether it ll occupy more heap space?

Comment: I don't think so :)